# Perl: Smartest and fastest way for (dividing) large script?

Tags: perl, perl-module, subroutine

I have a Perl Script, that has (as of now) 10 subs and growing..

Each sub is making a different LWP-Call and is working with a variable I set in the first sub.

As each sub takes some time, I'm looking for a smart way to make the script run faster.

What would you recommend?

Should I:

- Put each sub into a seperate script?
- Call the subs (except the first) at once?
- Use a different solution (that I don't know of)?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
The script is fetching some xml- and soap-data from the web, then extracting the necesary parts.

Comment: 10 subroutines in a script isn't very much.  And splitting up a script won't affect the running time noticeably unless it's enormous (many thousands of lines). It's hard to give any more help without more details about what the script is doing and how it's doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want check the  [LWP::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aParallel) module.

> ParallelUserAgent is an extension to the existing libwww module. It
>   allows you to take a list of URLs (it currently supports HTTP, FTP,
>   and FILE URLs. HTTPS might work, too) and connect to all of them *in
>   parallel*, then wait for the results to come in.

Comment: Thank you, it suits my needs best

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using Coro and there is already a module to do LWP requests.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::Coro::http](http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3aCoro%3a%3ahttp)

Coro is cooperative routines so not multithreaded. There is also an AnyEvent variation

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I like the LWP::Parallel module better.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to split up the file if you dont want to. Just take a list of things to run on STDIN, then execute your script multiple times putting each process in the background or use cron if its an on going thing.

I would recommend using the Operating System's processes until you have a good reason not to do so anymore.

Comment: I believe this will use more memory than the other solutions. Thanks anyhow

Comment: What do you mean by this and what leads you to believe it? Memory usage is something that is measured over a range of time. If you graph memory usage of one of your processes, you will see memory usage continue to grow until the process exits- however long that takes. If you split the work up into separate OS processes you may use more memory overall. But per process, you will use small amounts of memory for short amounts of time. Also, if in the future you hit some limit of memory/disk IO/network, it will be easy to add new nodes.